# Htaccess url mapping to a sub-folder of the same domain root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to rewrite the URLs from www.domain.com/examp1 to displays the content from a subfolder on the domain root /fodler1/folder2/ and I want all the URL on the website to be changed according to this rewriting.

I was excited to try this but I guess I didn't make it work!

Method I (Without URL change):
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Thanks

Comment: TO more clarify I want www.domain.com/example1 to display a website I installed on www.domain.com/folder1/folder2 so the subfolder I want to map to exist on the same domain root.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP multisite (subdomain) is can be used http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Moreover you can install the WP Domain Mapping Plugin to run on other domains

You need to decide whether you want WP multisite subdomain or sub-directory installation. WP subdomain does exactly what you want, but WP subdir + domain mapping plugin allows you to have both (subdomain AND sub-directory). WP subdomain looks like this: domain.com (main site) site1.domain.com site2.domain.com

WP subdirectory looks like this: domain.com (main site) domain.com/site1 domain.com/site2

With WP Domain Mapping plugin you can map any subsite above to another domain, for example: site1.domain.com -> www.site1.com site2.domain.com -> www.site2.com [or] domain.com/site1 -> www.site1.com domain.com/site2 -> www.site2.com

Got answer from - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/42826/user42826

Comment: thanks for your clarification, I guess I forgot to tell that I'm already using WP multisite and that I have the Domain Mapping plugin.